# localhost: data not going into database

Tags: php, sql, database, localhost

i am trying to make a registration system but when i register the data isn't there.

i tried to search same questions but i couldn't find the issue, and the worst is that the script detect the database but wont get the data in.

The PHP script :

```
<?php
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=fireblock', 'root', '');

if(isset($_POST['submitform'])) {
   $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
   $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
   $email2 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email2']);
   $pass = sha1($_POST['pass']);
   $pass2 = sha1($_POST['pass2']);
   if(!empty($_POST['username']) AND !empty($_POST['email']) AND !empty($_POST['email2']) AND !empty($_POST['pass']) AND !empty($_POST['pass2'])) {
      $usernamelength = strlen($username);
      if($usernamelength <= 255) {
          if($email == $email2) {
             if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $reqemail = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = ?");
                $reqemail->execute(array($email));
                $emailexist = $reqemail->rowCount();
                if($emailexist == 0) {
                   if($pass == $pass) {
                   $insertmbr = $bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO members(username, email, pass) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
                   $insertmbr->execute(array($username, $email, $pass));
                   $error = "Your account has been created! <a href=\"login.php\">Connect</a>";
                         } else {
                             $error = "Your passs are not the same!";
                         }
                         } else {
                           $error = "Email already used!";
                      }
                      } else {
                          $error = "Your email is invalid!";
                  }
                  } else {
                       $error = "Your emails are not the same!";
              }
              } else {
               $error = "Your username can't get upper than 255 characters!";
          }
          } else {
               $error = "Every fields should be filled!";
          }
      }
 ?>
```

Comment: things to check: 1. is everything there in `$_POST` that you expect? 2. do you hit the correct if block? 3. if so, is the data that you are trying to insert still there, and as expected? 4. how does the query look BEFORE trying to run it on the database - is anything missing/wrong? 5. does the query run on your database if you run it manually with the data it is failing with? 6. is all of your data correct for the defined columns? (the db could just be silently failing, especially if the only problem is that "the data is just is not there")

Comment: 1. yes 2. yes too 3.yes 4. nothing is missing 5. there is no errors 6.yes it is @peterxz

Comment: For debugging purpose, please change if(isset($_POST['submitform']))  to if (1==1) ; and please add the ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); at the top of your php script so that the system can display what are the errors. Let's us know the result. Thanks